# Why is my code not running within a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

THe following code fails to run when I add a  for loop. Why is this happening?

```
library(igraph)
library(MASS)
g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(10, .7, directed = FALSE) #creating random graph
E(g01)$weight <- runif(length(E(g01)), 0,4) #adding edge weight
plot(g01, edge.width=E(g01)$weight) #plotting
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(g01, attr = "weight") #converting graph to matrix
B <- mean(A) #matrix mean
C <- A-B #subtracti ng mean
diag(C) <- 0 #keeping diagonal 0
D <- (C)^2/100 #reqd calculation
Ssum <- sum(D)/2 #reqd calculation
print(Ssum)
```

Here is the same code within the loop:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
    g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(10, .7, directed = FALSE)
    E(g01)$weight <- runif(length(E(g01)), 0, 4)
    plot(g01, edge.width = E(g01)$weight)
    A <- as_adjacency_matrix(g01, attr = "weight")
    B <- mean(A)
    C <- A - B
    diag(C) <- 0 
    D <- (C)^2/100
    Ssum <- sum(D)/2
    print(Ssum)
}
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated,
Ishani Mukherjee

Comment: What is `erdos.renyi.game`?

Comment: Please format your question in a way that it can be reproduced! Consider adding sample data, libraries used and versions.

Comment: erdos.renyi.game generates a random network. Here, I have specified the number of nodes (=10) and the probability of connections within each node (=0.7)

Comment: @VishalA. I have now included libraries in question.

Comment: The line `B <- mean(A)` results in NA even w/o loop, is that what you want? Perhaps you want `B <- mean(as.numeric(A))`?

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you so much! I am new to this, I struggle and make errors. My code runs now. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.